# Developing a blog site, having issues displaying text while in edit mode

Tags: php, html, blogs, line-breaks

Blog body variable is being saved into mysql as:

```
$body = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['body']);
```

Extracting it from DB like:

```
$body = nl2br($row['body']);
```

and using `echo $body` to show it.

I want users to be able to embed video, and use html tags in their blogs, the issue I'm having is when the user enters "edit" mode to change the blog, you can see all of the html linkbreak tags.  Is there a way to show all html tags except for the linebreak tag?

Comment: Don't use `nl2br` when editing

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that are going on with your code sample. First, you should be using `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead of `mysql_real_escape_string`, here are [a few reasons](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=mysql%20versus%20mysqli) why.

Second, you don't want to use `nl2br` until you're displaying the text.